# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable for JSON parsing

Tags: python, json, request

I am trying to extract event's fee information from this [website](https://www.eventbrite.com/d/malaysia--kuala-lumpur--85675181/all-events/?page=1) from pages 1 to 20 using python. The event's fee is from external URL. Therefore, i need to parse it using json load and extract the pattern from the json file.  I have try the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63390671/python-web-scrapping-html-with-same-class) and get the following error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. Based on my research, it means that the object equal to None and therefore, not subscriptable.

I have try to assign the object to 'NA' if value is None but still no successful. I would appreciate if anyone can kindly explain. Below is the code that i have try:

```
import re
import json
import requests

event_fees = []

for i in range(20):
    
    urls = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/d/malaysia--kuala-lumpur--85675181/all-events/?page=' + str(i)
    
    events_url = 'https://www.eventbrite.com/api/v3/destination/events/?event_ids={event_ids}&expand=event_sales_status,primary_venue,image,saves,my_collections,ticket_availability&page_size=99999'
    
    html_text = requests.get(urls).text
    
    data1 = json.loads( re.search(r'window\.__SERVER_DATA__ = ({.*});', html_text).group(1) )
    
    event_ids = ','.join(r['id'] for r in data1['search_data']['events']['results'])
    data2 = requests.get(events_url.format(event_ids=event_ids)).json()
    
    for e in data2['events']:
        fees = (e['ticket_availability']['minimum_ticket_price']['display'],'to',e['ticket_availability']['maximum_ticket_price']['display'])
        if fees is None:
            
            event_fees.append("NA")
        
        else:
            
            event_fees.append(fees)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? You seem to know how to write an `if` statement to check whether something is `None`, why don’t you do the same for the object that gives you the error?

Comment: I need to write the code so that if the object is None,  it will assign NA to the event_fees list while if they is fees value in object, it will append the fees value to the event_fees.

Comment: That is a task description, not a question. What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: I got this 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable which i don't understand how to solve.

Comment: You need to check if the object is `None` before trying to use `[]` with it. If it is `None` you need to do something else (for example, nothing). Since you are already using `if fees is None` in the code I am wondering why you do not use another such check where it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a key in that object before use subscription(`obj['key']`). In this case `data2[6]['ticket_availability']['minimum_ticket_price']` is `None`.

Comment: If the key is None(without fees), how can i assign it as 'NA' and pass it to event_fees  list  while if others object have fees value, it will append to the event_fees list.